# How to find and characterise critical points of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Find and characterise the critical points of: $f(x)=(2x^3-12x^2+18x-1)^5$

I differentiated to get:

$$\frac{df}{dx}=5(6x^2-24x+18)(2x^3-12x^2+18x-1)^4=30(x-3)(x-1)(2x^3-12x^2+18x-1)^4$$

But don't know how to factorise this further?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+(2x%5E3+-12x%5E2+%2B18x-1)%5E5

Answer (score 0):

If you set $$30(x-3)(x-1)(2x^3-12x^2+18x-1)^4=0$$ then the stationary points are at $$x-3=0\implies x=3\\x-1=0\implies x=1\\2x^3-12x^2+18x-1=0$$ and this cubic equation can be solved using Cardano's method.

To find the critical points, substitute each value of $x$ into $y=(2x^3-12x^2+18x-1)^5$ and the nature of them can be found by evaluating the second derivative of $y$ at those points.

Comment: How do I solve the cubic equation?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients)